# Setting the button's background in a windows store app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I wish some one could help me out in my problem since I am new to C# programming language.
I have been facing difficulties inserting an image to a button using C# language. I have been succeeded by relying on the XAMl representation, but I need to know how to accomplish this task using the C# language.

I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: What have you tried and can you provide an example of the code that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this XAML

```
  <Grid>
        <Button Height="100" Width="100">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="imgpath.png"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
```

**source:** 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devschool/archive/2011/06/27/make-an-image-button-using-xaml-it-s-easy-and-fun.aspx

Comment: Dear Zach... Thank you soo much and I appreciate your help, but could you please help me out finding a solution using the C# and not the XAML one since I have already found the approach.